# datetime.utcfromtimestamp changing time in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc

I have a string representing a datetime (ts). I want to transform it to int and then use
`datetime.utcfromtimestamp` to recover the same datetime:

```py
ts = '2023-07-10 14:06:22.000 UTC'
int_ts = int(datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z").timestamp() * 1000) # change this line, cannot change the previous or next
back_to_ts = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int_ts / 1000)
print(f"{back_to_ts = }, {ts = }, {int_ts = }")
```

However, I get the following output:

```
back_to_ts = datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 10, 12, 6, 22), ts = '2023-07-10 14:06:22.000 UTC', int_ts = 1688990782000
```

I can only change the second line, how should I change it to get the follwoing output?

```
back_to_ts = datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 10, 14, 6, 22), ts = '2023-07-10 14:06:22.000 UTC', int_ts = 1688990782000
```

Comment: `%Z` might be misleading here; it basically makes the parser *ignore* the fact that the input specifies UTC. The resulting datetime object will be naive, no timezone set. Regarding `utcfromtimestamp` consider [this](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html). Using `fromtimestamp`  with the tz argument set might be the better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the timezone in your datetime object before the converting it to a timestamp. See the `.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)` part of the second line.

```
ts = '2023-07-10 14:06:22.000 UTC'
int_ts = int(datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000)
back_to_ts = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int_ts / 1000)
```

Output:

```
back_to_ts = datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 10, 14, 6, 22), ts = '2023-07-10 14:06:22.000 UTC', int_ts = 1688997982000
```

Comment: an alternative for replacing the tzinfo would be to modify the input string: `datetime.fromisoformat(ts.replace(" UTC", "+00:00"))`

Comment: forgot to add that timezone is imported from datetime, but yeah, it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the pytz library to parse the input datetime string to handle the UTC timezone correctly. Just need to change the second line. Here is the modified code:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

ts = '2023-07-10 14:06:22.000 UTC'
int_ts = int(pytz.utc.localize(datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z")).timestamp() * 1000)
back_to_ts = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int_ts / 1000)
print(f"{back_to_ts = }, {ts = }, {int_ts = }")
```

Output:

```
back_to_ts = datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 10, 14, 6, 22), ts = '2023-07-10 14:06:22.000 UTC', int_ts = 1688990782000
```